# QProgressBar PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a QPushButton which when clicked runs a function to plot a graph.

I want a progressbar below that QPushButton showing busy indicator. I dnt want the percentage or any logic in the bar just the looping type bar we get by setting -

```
self.progressbar.setMinimum(0)
self.progressbar.setMaximum(0)
```

I dnt want this bar to show in the UI initially so i have set-

```
self.progressbar.setVisible(False)
```

And then this to show the bar:

```
def functiontoplotgraph(self):
    self.progressbar.setVisible(True)
    ---#code to plot graph
    self.progressbar.hide()
```

My problem is the bar shows after the data is plotted. i want it to show when i click the button and hide when plot is shown.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Import `QApplication` and call `QApplication.processEvents()` immediately after `self.progressbar.setVisible(True)`.

The reason is that many actions are not done immediately as you call them in code (typically showing/hiding/resizing/layouting) but are queued in even queue. By calling `processEvents()` you will force to do them right away. So I assume this should help.

In some cases you should also try `QApplication.sendPostedEvents()` before `processEvents()`.

Comment: it shows now right after clicking the button but not as i want. The loading bar is shown without the busy indicator. Chunks are not visible.

Comment: Earlier when it showed after the graph the bar chunks were showing left to right in a loop. Now after this the progressbar appears in coorect time but a empty bar.

Comment: This is because you GUI thread is blocked by plotting the graph. You either have to periodically call `processEvents()` during plotting (which is simpler but sometimes not possible if you do not have access to the code which plots the graph) or you have to plot your graph in a separate thread (which may be also very very complicated and sometimes not possible). So it depends on the code you use to plot the graph. And it is a completely different question. Your question as was asked has been answered.